# How can i use generic list with foreach?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

if i compiled below codes error return foreach loop how can i solve it?

**Error:Error  1   foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'Sortlist.MyCalısan' because 'Sortlist.MyCalısan' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'    C:\Users\yusuf.karatoprak\Desktop\ExcelToSql\TestExceltoSql\Sortlist\Program.cs 46  13  Sortlist**

```
        static void EskiMetodlaListele()
        {
            MyCalısan myCalısan = new MyCalısan();
            Calısan calisan = new Calısan();
            calisan.Ad = "ali";
            calisan.SoyAd = "abdullah";
            calisan.ID = 1;

            myCalısan.list.Add(calisan);

            foreach (Calısan item in myCalısan)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Ad.ToString());
            }
        }


    }

   public class Calısan
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Ad { get; set; }
        public string SoyAd { get; set; }

    }

   public class MyCalısan
    {
        public List<Calısan> list { get; set; }
        public MyCalısan()
        {
            list = new List();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only write `foreach (Calısan item in myCalısan.list)`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `MyCalısan` to define as Collection.

```
public class MyCalısan : Collection<Calısan>
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the *collection* you had defined - the `list` property:

```
myCalısan.list.Add(calısan);

foreach (Calısan item in myCalısan.list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Ad.ToString());
}
```

However, if you want to iterate over `myCalısan` directly, make the `MyCalısan` class implement `IEnumerable<Calısan>`.

Comment: List is initialized in constructor MyCalısan()

Comment: @Belousov Pavel - yeah noticed that after posting my answer. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You should loop on MyCalisan.list; MyCalisan is just your class, and is not enumerable itself.

Answer (score 0):

a few issues need to be fixed before it will compile:

```
   public class MyCalısan{
public List<Calısan> list { get; set; }
public MyCalısan()
{
    list = new List<Calısan>();
}}

  foreach (Calısan item in myCalısan.list)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Ad.ToString());
        }
```